# Error occurs when updating to meteor1.4

Tags: meteor

My current version is 1.3.5, and I tried to update my meteor to 1.4.
However it stop in line： fourseven:scss 3.8.0 1.
I think I install meteor 1.4 successfully.(i'm not good at English...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall and be sure to have proper internet connection

Comment: My project with meteor 1.4 works as long as I don't use scss

Comment: finally,every time i update meteor failed and appear that error, i use robocopy to copy that file from others.(i use windows...)